# Linq: Filter by calculation result and reuse this result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a collection (in a DbSet) that I want sort by a calculation result of its property (distance) and transform it (re-using the distance) to a different model. The calculation should happen only once per entry (and as its a DbSet, it'll be executed in the DB itself).

```
class InputModel {
    Vector3 position;
}

class OutputModel {
    double distance;
}

var inputList = getInputList(); // returns IQueryable<InputModel>

var outputList = inputList
.Where( x => (){
    var dist = calculateDistance( x.position );
    // calculateDistance() boils down to a simple equation that could directly translated to an sql-query (when typed in statically by hand)
    return dist < maxDistance;
})
.Select( x => () {
    return new OutputModel {
        distance = ???; // get the calculated distance somehow
})
.ToList();
```

Two possible solutions come to my mind:

1. Get all entries out of the database into a container and calculate the distance and filter entries out in a foreach-loop.
2. Filter by distance and recalculate the distance when transforming to the OutputModel.

Is it possible to do this in one go (preferred is the calculation in the DB itself)?

Comment: **1.** Linq to Entities provider wouldn't let you use `calculateDistance()` in your `Where()`. Show its code so we can know whether it can be broken down to something the provider *would* be able to translate.  **2.** Does `getInputList()` return `IQueryable<InputModel>`?

Comment: `calculateDistance()` is a simple math function that the db (SQL) supports (however I don't know if it will be directly translated to sql-statements, i don't have any expirience in this). Yes, `IQueryable<InputModel>` is the container to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do inputlist.where(....).select(x=>calculatedistance).select(dist=> new outputmodel)... Commenting from my mobile so cannot type out full statement. But should point you in right direction. Basically. Fist do the where then select distance. Then select output model

Answer (score 0):

You can Make selection first and then use the selected values in you comparision.

Please give a try

```
var outputList = InputList
                 .Select(
                     x => new 
                      {
                        dist = calculateDistance( x.position )
                      }     
                  )
                 .Where(x => x.dist < maxDistance)
                 .Select(y => () {
                 return new OutputModel {
                     distance = y.dist // get the calculated distance Here
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to use both the distance you calculate from the entity and the entity itself for your `OutputModel` projection, you simply need to project the calculation with it's entity as an anonymous type when you perform the calculation:

```
var outputList = inputList
    .Select( x => new 
        {
            dist = calculateDistance( x.position ),
            entity = x
        } )
    .Where( x => x.dist < maxDistance )
    .Select( x => new OutputModel 
        {
            distance = x.dist,
            // and you have access to source entity via `x.entity`
        } )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ query syntax naturally supports this with the [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause.

Here is how it can be applied to your scenario:

```
var outputList = 
    (from x in inputList
     let distance = ... // distance calculation expression using x
     where distance < maxDistance
     select new OutputModel { distance }
    ).ToList();
```